# Will this unicode encryption fail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, unicode, plist

I'm not needing any serious security, I just need to stop 11 year olds with plist editors from editing their number of coins in my game with ease.

I created a function that takes a string, for each unicode value of a character it raises this unicode value by 220 plus 14 times the character number that it is in the string.

Obviously this will fail (I think) if the string was like a million characters long because eventually you run out of unicode characters, but for all intents and purposes, this will only be used on strings of 20 characters and less.

Are there any unicode characters in this range that will not be stored to a plist or will be ignored by Apple's underlying code when I save the plist so that when I retrieve it and decrypt the character will be gone and I can't decrypt it?

```
+(NSString*)encryptString:(NSString*)theString {
    NSMutableString *encryptedFinal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
        unichar uniCharacter = [theString characterAtIndex:i];
        uniCharacter += +220+(14*i);
        [encryptedFinal appendFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter];
    }
    return encryptedFinal;
}

+(NSString*)decryptString:(NSString*)theString {
    NSMutableString *decryptedFinal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
        unichar uniCharacter = [theString characterAtIndex:i];
        uniCharacter += +220+(14*i);
        [decryptedFinal appendFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter];
    }
    return decryptedFinal;
}
```

Comment: Unicode does not work that way. Not all values are valid unicode values. One thing you can do is convert the `NSString` to an `NSData`, manipulate the data.

Comment: You don't need this. Until and unless the iPhone/iPad is jailbroken there is no way to modify an app's .plist files. If the iPhone/iPad is jailbroken, then a code injector will be able to defeat almost all simple encryption schemes.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843496/encrypt-decrypt-plist-file-ios?rq=1)

Comment: @Pranav Thousands of our users are modifying their plists without jailbreak simply by plugging their devices into the computers. There are hundreds of videos that middle schoolers are publishing and it has started impacting our in-app purchase sales.

Comment: @Zaph This is what I feared. So are any unicode characters within my range invalid? Also, if I use an invalid unicode character, does the NSData just completely erase it so it can't be decrypted? Or does it just store a "broken" character that's value can later be returned to the decrypted version?

Comment: Why do you try to come up with your own encryption scheme if just using standard encryption routines is so much easier? Are you afraid that it becomes too secure? I'm always amazed when people want simple encryption and then go for some haphazard scheme instead of simply calling a function of the supplied libs.

Comment: @owlstead I tried for an hour to get AES encryption and decryption working or any other encryption or decryption working and was unsuccessful, I can hardly find anything about it online, most references I find are just copy-pasted "solutions" that don't have enough information for me to implement. They all contain frameworks or libraries that I don't actually have and can't seem to find anywhere. I finally gave up and just made my own. I'm wondering when and if it will fail due to invalid unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for a range of a string of length 20 characters or less if you are encrypting one of the first 26+26+10+30 characters in the unicode index at any given point along the 20 character line. It probably works higher, I just didn't test it any higher.

This is the code I created to test it, all unicode characters were stored in an NSString and stayed valid for counting later.

```
    int i = 0;
    NSMutableString *encryptedFinal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSString *theString = @"a";
    int j = 26+26+10+30;//letters + capital letters + numbers + 30 extra things like ?><.\]!@$
    int f = 0;
    int z = 0;
    while (f < j) {
        while (i < 220+220+(14*20)) {
            unichar uniCharacter = [theString characterAtIndex:0];
            uniCharacter += +f;
            uniCharacter += +220+(14*i);
            [encryptedFinal appendFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter];
            i++;
        }
        z += i;
        f++;
        i = 0;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", encryptedFinal);
    NSLog(@"%i == %i?", z, encryptedFinal.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing that you can do:

1. Save the number of coins using `NSData` rather than using
   `NSNumber`. Then use
   [NSData+AES](https://github.com/nicerobot/objc/tree/master/NSData/NSData%2BAES)
   to encrypt it. You can even encrypt your entire .plist file to
   ensure that no other fields are changed.
2. Security through obscurity. Just save the number of coins as an important sounding           field. e.g.:Security Token Number. You can also create a bogus number of coins field whose value is ignored. Or maybe save the same value in both the fields and flag the user for cheating if the two values don't match.